# I need to generate Average Response time and Average latency time .csv files for my JMeter test Plan

Tags: graph, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, reportgenerator

I need to generate Average Response time and Average latency time . csv files.

I have 50 API's in a web application and I need to test it for up to 50 concurrent users.

I have tried Aggregate Graph and its plugin, but it only generates average elapsed time.
For Example this I have got for Aggregate Elapsed time:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzE08.png)

My client has asked me to generate similar spread sheet report for Average Response time and Average latency time with their graphs.

Can someone help me if there is any way in JMeter to accomplish it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSMka.png)
Presently I've generated this graph using average elapsed time data from Aggregate Report for 5 concurrent users.

Note* - I'm a beginner in JMeter, so please explain me in simple terms if possible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) which contains:

- Response times Over Time
- Latencies Over Time
- and several more charts

The command to [run JMeter your test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/) and generate the HTML report will be:

```
jmeter -n -t /path/to/yout/testplan.jmx -l /path/to/results.csv-e -o /path/to/html/report/folder
```

If for some reason you have to run tests in GUI mode (although it violates [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)) you can use [Response Times Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime) and [Response Latencies Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/LatenciesOverTime), the custom charts can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Comment: Yes brother I did that as well it has generated a detailed report , I did not use command line I did it with Tools>>Generate HTML Report 

But the thing is I find it very complex, just imaging If I run 50 API's for 50 users how complex it will become.

Comment: I used 2 plugins as well:
--jp@gc - Response Latencies Over Time
--jp@gc - Response Times Over Time

But the Aggregate graph its generating is giving very simple graph but without any detailing related to API's.

So, is there any way I can change the user.properties and add another column in aggregate report for avg latencies and Avg Response time?

If I get that I can simply  generate a graph in MS excel for that, I hope you got me :)

Comment: JMeter's .jtl result file is a normal CSV file, you should be able to generate any chart you want in MS Excel. Graph for the average response time will be a single dot. I hope you got me.

Comment: One more question is elapsed time == response time??
Is there any formula to calculate Response time ?
I see there are 3 columns in excel sheet Elapsed time, latency, time to connect.
From all these 3 columns how can I calculate response time

Comment: The formula is one post - one question, comments section is not designed for asking questions which are not related to the initial one. As an exception: Elapsed time is Response Time, it can be calculated as `Elapsed time = connect time + latency + time to last byte`. See [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) and [Understanding Your Reports: Part 1 - What are KPIs?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-kpis-part-1-what-are-kpis?utm_source=Blog&utm_medium=BM_Blog&utm_campaign=kpis-part4) articles. I hope you got me.